# Where can I find the book of Mudora?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I am playing through the Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past. I have completed the first dungeon and I'm looking for the way into the second, but it appears to be blocked by stone. I found a cave with an old man in it, and he says that in order to get into this second dungeon I must find the book of Mudora, which should be located in the house of books.

Where is the book of Mudora? Where is the house of books?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Book of Mudora is in the library just south of Kakariko village. It's on top of a book shelf that you have to use your Peagus Boots to slam into. After ramming into the book shelf, the book falls off and you can grab it. Here's a video showing this: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SD9FDoyLSk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_SD9FDoyLSk#t=197s)

Here's an image showing it. It's number 15:

> [image: SPOILER ALERT: ITEM LOCATIONS IN LIGHT WORLD]

Answer (score 12):

The House of Books is a library located on the southern side of Kakariko Village.

[image]

The library itself is elevated on a hill, with a book and quill plaque on the front of the building:

[image]

The book of Mudora is located inside on top of a bookshelf to the left, you will need to run at the bookshelf in order to knock the book off the top:

[image]